# How to run migrations for test suite.

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rspec

I have a ruby app that uses ActiveRecord and sqllite. I am trying to write tests but I get this error:

```
 Failure/Error: user = described_class.create(name: name)

     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'users'
```

This is my gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "sinatra-activerecord"
gem "sqlite3"

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

group :test, :development do
  gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.1.0"
  gem "pry"
end
```

I have a spec_helper that looks like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|


  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'sqlite3', database: 'db/test.db')
end
```

What can I do to create a test database and run the migrations for my sqllite tests?

Answer (score 3):

`bin/rails RAILS_ENV=test db:migrate` and/or `bin/rails db:test:prepare` will update your test db. You also might want to check out the [Rails Testing Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-test-database) too - lots of helpful info there. Or if you want to avoid fixtures, [FactoryBot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails) is great for generating test data.

Comment: Ginnie's answer here is perfect, except that the OP doesn't specify the app uses Rails. ActiveRecord tasks/migrations are a great solution to the question being asked, and can be done outside of Rails (though it requires some extra tinkering). Toss `rails` into the `Gemfile` for an easy solution, or give the migrations guide a good read-through to better understand the api: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Comment: Good point, Sean Huber, I didn't notice the sinatra gem. I don't use Sinatra much. Would the "rspec-rails" gem be expect to work with Sinatra?

Comment: Well from the runtime dependencies listed in rspec-rails, https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/rspec-rails.gemspec, I see runtime dependencies of activesupport, actionpack, and railties. I'm sure you could set up a project with just sinatra and these rails components and have rspec-rails + active record migrations work.  But in my opinion if you bring in all these rails gems, you might as well just build your app on top of rails instead of piecing it all together yourself. Good question.

Comment: Also `db:test:prepare` was deprecated in `4.1` and has since been removed completely

Answer (score 2):

Ginnie's answer can work, but if like Sean mentionned you need an ActiveRecord only solution instead of using Rails consider this :

I recently developed a gem to bundle some ActiveRecord models without using Rails.
Here is what I did to test my models with rspec:

**spec/spec_helper.rb:**

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'sqlite3',
                                        database: ':memory:')
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  require_relative '../lib/db/migrate/create_models'
end
```

**lib/db/migrate/create_models.rb:** (to make this file I copy/pasted the actual schema.rb generated by migrations)

```
class CreateModels < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
 create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string "uid", default: "", null: false
   t.string "email", null: false
   // other attributes
 end
 // other tables
end
```

This will create your needed tables for your tests to run.

Don't forget to require spec_helper in your *_spec.rb file and you're good to go.